# Weird text on console before the login interface in Deepin 20

Tags: linux, console

I'm a linux Deepin 20 user and I've installed it this week. I've noticed that when starting my laptop, a message containing some sort of errors appears on the black screen and then dissappears, the login interface comes and everything works well.

Here is the text that appears everytime I start the laptop :

[image: text]

So I'm wondering what do these errors mean?

How can I fix them ?

How can I make my laptop start without displaying this ?

Are the values that I hid worth being hidden ? (funny question I know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first message about "VMX" stands for Virtual Machine Extensions, and you can learn more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization).

You can get rid of this message by going into your BIOS settings and enabling it, typically under the name of "Virtualization Technology" or similar.

Comment: Thanks, but could you edit your answer and make it a little more detailed. Could you tell me what are the 2 other errors?

Comment: The other two errors are related to the first error, I think. Did they all go away once you enabled VMX?

Comment: I haven't enabled it yet

Comment: Enable it then check if they're all gone.

Comment: I've just enabled it, the previous errors have gone but a new one has occured. I couldn't read it entirely as it was displayed for a short time, but it was related to a driver update I think.

Comment: You should probably make a new post about that new error message once you can figure out what it said or you get an image of it.

Comment: Okay, but one more thing, is it safe now that the VMX is enabled ? because before doing so, I read an indication in the BIOS settings saying that it's prefered to keep it disabled

Comment: If you don't need to emulate anything, it's better to just leave it off.